# Javascript-moving image

Tags: javascript

How is it posible move an image from one position to other with fadeout?
I hav such functions

for hiding:

```
function SetOpacity(object,opacityPct)
{
  // IE.
  object.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacityPct + ')';
  // Old mozilla and firefox
  object.style.MozOpacity = opacityPct/100;
  // Everything else.
  object.style.opacity = opacityPct/100;
}
function ChangeOpacity(id,msDuration,msStart,fromO,toO)
{
  var element=document.getElementById(id);
  var opacity = element.style.opacity * 100;
  var msNow = (new Date()).getTime();
  opacity = fromO + (toO - fromO) * (msNow - msStart) / msDuration;
  if (opacity<0) 
    SetOpacity(element,0)
  else if (opacity>100)
    SetOpacity(element,100)
  else
  {
    SetOpacity(element,opacity);
    element.timer = window.setTimeout("ChangeOpacity('" + id + "'," + msDuration + "," + msStart + "," + fromO + "," + toO + ")",1);
  }
}

function FadeOut(id)
{
  var element=document.getElementById(id);
  if (element.timer) window.clearTimeout(element.timer); 
  var startMS = (new Date()).getTime();
  element.timer = window.setTimeout("ChangeOpacity('" + id + "',500," + startMS + ",100,0)",1);
}
```

for get current position or next position (by id of image and id of div)

```
function findPos(e){
var obj = document.getElementById(e);
var posX = obj.offsetLeft;var posY = obj.offsetTop;
while(obj.offsetParent){
posX=posX+obj.offsetParent.offsetLeft;
posY=posY+obj.offsetParent.offsetTop;
if(obj==document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){break}
else{obj=obj.offsetParent;}
}
alert(posX+'-'+posY);
}
```

the first position is position of image, and next - is position of div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach with minimal code will be to use jQuery and use the animate function mate.

Ex:

```
$(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
```

You can use multiple parameters in the brackets like background-color, opacity, etc as you wish to dynamically change the values.

A link for your reference is located at:  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Most javascript animations rely on timer to create the effect of fluid motion. To slide an image across the page, you would set an interval that changed the css position to the right 1px every 5 milliseconds or something of the like. [Javascript animation tutorial.](http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/)

However, animation is most easily accomplished with a library like jquery or [many others.](http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/10-impressive-javascript-animation-frameworks/)